# Removing documents in Gensim

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, gensim

I'm using Gensim for an NLP task and currently I have a corpus which includes empty documents.  I don't want to rerun my code, although that is an option, and would just like to remove the documents that don't have any content.  The documents are already saved as TF-IDF corpora and was wondering if there was a way to remove these documents that are empty.  I can figure out which documents are empty but the corpora file is an iterator and not any type of data structure ie list.  Thanks,

Cameron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try converting the corpus to a numpy matrix, like so:

```
numpy_matrix = gensim.matutils.corpus2dense(corpus, num_terms=number_of_corpus_features)
```

Then remove the appropriate columns (those with all zero entries).  Then convert back to a gensim corpus to continue:

```
corpus = gensim.matutils.Dense2Corpus(numpy_matrix)
```

If you plan on building any more corpora in your current context, it might be a good idea to modify the corpus creation process so you don't have to do this every time, but I'm sure you've thought of that.